# Cmake cannot generate shared library, but static library is generated

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I want to generate a shared library with CMake, and even though I do not get any errors, the library (.so file) is not generated.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(myTest)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --std=c++0x -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC")


add_definitions(-DLINUX=1)

include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/public/include
  # .. bunch of other include directories
  )

link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/shared/lib")


file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/some1.cpp"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/some2.cpp"
   )

add_library(myTest SHARED ${SRC_FILES})
```

When I create build dir, generate make files from cmake and execute the default the make target, I do not see any errors.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object /path/to/some1.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object /path/to/some2.cpp.o 
Linking CXX shared library myTest.so
g++: warning: /path/to/some1.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: /path/to/some2.cpp.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
[100%] Built target myTest
```

But when I see in my build folder, the so file, `libmytest.so` is not generated. It is not generated anywhere else as I did a find on my entire system.

Surprisingly, when I change the library type to be `STATIC`, the `libmytest.a` file is generated. Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: I would suspect the -c flag in your `set(CMAKE_C[XX]_FLAGS...)`. They're not needed since CMake will know to create Makefiles with rules that create the .o files for the appropriate source files.

Comment: Ah.. that was it. . Missed it . . Had copied the CXX_FLAGS from eclipse and forgot to remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was in the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. For compiling from `.cpp` to `.o`, g++ needs the -c flags, but cmake will automatically add it for us.

But while generating the `.so` library, g++ cannot understand the meaning of -c flag. Hence it was not generating the `.so` file, without giving any error as well.

After removing `-c` flag, it was able to generate the .so shared library.

Note that for generating static library, `ar` archiver is used instead of g++ , hence static library was generated without being affected.